# C# Error with Online Chat Room

Tags: c#, server, client

So I am making an online chat room in C#, and I am getting this error on line 71.

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.'

I have both a client program and a server program. Here is the code to the client program. The line that is giving me the error is in asterisks.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Threading;

    namespace ChatProgram
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new 
    System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
    NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);
    string readData = null;

    static int maxUsage = 0;
    string noName = "Anonymous";
    int tick = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void enterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(readRichTxt.Text + "$");
        serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
        serverStream.Flush();

        readData = "Connected to server...";
        msg();
        clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
        serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

        Thread ctThread = new Thread(getMessage);
        ctThread.Start();

        string nameTxt = nameTextBox.Text;
        if (nameTxt == String.Empty)
        {
            nameTxt = noName;
            tick = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            tick = 0;
        }
        readRichTxt.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
        readRichTxt.AppendText("\n" + nameTxt + " has joined." + "\n");
        ++maxUsage;
        sendButton.Enabled = true;

        if (maxUsage == 3)
        {
            enterButton.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void getMessage()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            int buffSize = 0;
            byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
            buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
            ***serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);***
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            readData = "" + returndata;
            msg();
        }
    }

    private void msg()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(msg));
        else
            readRichTxt.Text = readRichTxt.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + readData;
    }

    private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nameTxt = nameTextBox.Text;
        string userTyped = userTypeBox.Text;

        if (userTyped == String.Empty)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (tick == 1)
        {
            readRichTxt.AppendText(noName + ": " + userTyped);
        }
        else
        {
            readRichTxt.AppendText(nameTxt + ": " + userTyped);
        }
        userTypeBox.Clear();
    }
}
}
```

Please help, I am completely stumped at this point.

Comment: What line is that error on?

Comment: You're declaring inStream to be an array of 10025 bytes. Likely the stream you are trying to read is larger than this, causing the out of range exception. Instead, try declaring it `new byte[buffSize]` after you get the buffer length.

Answer (score 0):

what is the size of:

```
buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
```

?

this is likely larger than what you declared here:

```
byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
```

and thus the error is roughly telling you:

```
buffSize > inStream.Length
```

which results in the out of bounds like error.